# Adding emojis with python on discord

Tags: python, discord.py

im trying to add emojis via discord.py

It keeos saying invalid image type

```
@client.command()
async def emoji(ctx):
  await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name = ('ghostface'), image = (b'ghostface1.png'))
```

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: Unsupported image type given
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_custom_emoji), the `image` parameter represents the image *binary data*, not a *path* to an image.

Answer (score 1):

Image should be a bytes-like object not a path, you have to first read it.

Try this:

```
        with open(image_path, "rb") as file:
            new_emoji = file.read()
            await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name='ghostface', image=new_emoji)
```

Comment: A context manager for the image would be a bit better, but this works as well.

Answer (score -1):

After reading your question, I believe you could implement an emoji into a string. Results may very based on your version of python, but if your issue is different than what I stated, then please advise me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).